# Preventing fake accounts

Tags: security, authentication

I'm working on a simple web service that allows users to sign up for free and upload a small amount of data. I can easily establish a quota for each user, but malicious users could create fake accounts to upload as much data as they like in a denial-of-service attack.

Obviously, there's no perfect defense against this type of attack, but what can we do to mitigate this problem?

Comment: There's not much you can _really_ do, unless you require email validation and blacklist all the major freemail providers (and then you won't have any users!). And even that will not stop someone malicious, it's only 5 minutes more work.

Comment: Don't lose sleep over it ... it doesn't matter how much effort you put into preventing DOS attacks - someone else is finding a way to break your algorithm 5 minutes after you've implemented it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tie it to a more-or-less unique identifier (phone number, bank account number, facebook/google/etc account) or to a finite resource (such as time, by using a captcha).

Comment: My plan is to require users to validate their email address and solve a reCAPTCHA, or to login in with FB/Google/Twitter, all of whom validate email addresses and require CAPTCHAs; their systems for handling fake accounts are at least as good as mine.

Answer (score 2):

1. use a captcha on account creation to ensure that it's a
   human and not an automated process.
2. require a valid email address and require that they click a link in their email to validate that that's their email address and continue the registration process. This cuts down on their ability to create many throwaway accounts because you can limit them to only having one account per email address and they have to then create a new email address for each account they want to create.

Comment: Regarding requiring valid emails, make sure that filter for known throwaway email account providers such as mailinator.com.

Comment: Google's [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is really good at stopping bot automation.

Answer (score 0):

When the user signs up, the user supplies a valid email. Most accounts are not **enabled** until a response has been received, usually by clicking a link in the body of that email. When that click-through is received, you should be able to grab an IP address. That should help you curtail an abundance of casual DOS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

### Consider Phone Number Verification

Requiring phone number for account creation is the best approach I've come across; Creating a new email or cycling an IP address is pretty trivial, but genuine sms phone numbers cost money to activate & grant your service the ability to restrict access by country-code.

An important caveat: Virtual phone numbers (like google-voice), temporary-phone number services, & burner phones can make sms-verification ineffective at preventing duplicate user accounts. Depending on your use case, it might be worthwhile to use a service, like [Vonage's Number Insight api](https://www.vonage.com/communications-apis/number-insight/), that lets you identify those types of numbers.

[Authillo](https://authillo.com) is a passwordless authentication provider that prevents duplicate/fake accounts by leveraging sms verification, liveness detection, & facial recognition. Depending on how critical it is that you prevent fake accounts on your service, their base plan might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Which is the source?

Comment: @horcrux - apologies, this was my first response & didn't realize the ">" in markdown indicated that was quoting something. [This AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/preventing-free-trial-abuse-with-aws-managed-services/) advocates for verifying phone number & email

Answer (score -3):

Just log the IPs and assume the same user if the IP does not change within a time interval. This is bad, because it would prevent multiple users in the same house (same IP) but it is a good start.

Comment: As you said yourself, that is a bad solution. A bad solution is not a good start.